# Mis-spelling in the .NET configuration system, a design flaw?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration

I just wrote some .NET code to get connection string from the config file. The config file is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="key1" value="hello,world!"/>
  </appSettings>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="conn1" connectionString="abcd"/>
  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

.NET Framework provide the following types to get the connection string:

1- **ConnectionStringsSection** : stands for the config section containing several connection strings

2- **ConnectionStringSettingsCollection** : stands for the connection string collection

3- **ConnectionStringSettings** : stands for a certain connection string.

.NET Framework also provide the following types to get the App Settings:

4- **AppSettingsSection**

5- **KeyValueConfigurationCollection**

6- **KeyValueConfigurationElement**

Compare 2 to 5, 3 to 6, why are there extra "**s**" in ConnectionStringSetting[s]Collection and ConnectionStringSetting[s]?

This mis-spelling is really mis-leading. I think it's a design flaw.

Has anyone noticed that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because its in English.  Settings implies multiple as does Configuration.  A configuration can have multiple properties but a setting is one 'thing'.  Configurations would imply a collection of multiple properties.  Not a typo just an English language quirk

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you said, "settings" implies plural. But one more thing, the ConnectionStringSettings type only stands for a single connection string, it doesn't make sense to use a plural word here, I think ConnectionString is good enough.

Comment: +1 "Because its in English" we really need some form of syntax highlighting or error checking for that language

Comment: @smwikipedia - its because when you access ConnectionStringSettings in code you are getting all of the settings for a single ConnectionString - ConnectionString, ProviderName...etc.

Comment: thanks very much~ that makes sense now. Grammar seems to be playing a non-trivial part in programming. :)